# Filter listviewwebpart programatically c#

Tags: list-view-web-part

I have created a webpart page called Home.aspx (under SitePages) and added a list view "My Department". The list shows all the list items irrespective of the currently logged in user's department.

Currently, to filter the list, I am appending the following to the URL and it's working:

`?FilterField1=Dept&FilterValue1=DeptName`

I can get the department name using C# code. Please let me know is there any better approach to filter the ListViewWebPart without modifying the URL.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This the best option. Other option is to create a new View and setting it to the web part.